# Javascript not getting invoked in HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html

My Javascript is not getting invoked in the HTML form. Please let me know where am I going wrong and how can i trace the call (application developed using python/flask).

This is my JAVAScript

```js
function UserDetailsVal()
 {
    var userId = documents.forms["userDetails"]["userId"].value;
    if (userId.value == "")
    {
        alert("Please Enter User ID")
        return false
    }
 }</script>
```

```html
 <div class="jumbotron">
         <h1>Display User Details</h1>
         <div class="jumbotron">
         <form name="userDetails" class=class="form-userDetails, action="/userDetails", method="POST">
             User ID:<input type="text" name="userId" value="{{request.form['userId']}}" class="form-control"
                  onsubmit="return UserDetailsVal(this)">
           <!--required placeholder="User ID"
             oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Enter the User ID')"
             oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')"  /> -->
             Name: {{ name }} </br>
             User Name: {{ userName }} </br>
             Password: {{ password }}  </br>
            <button id="btnretive" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Retrive</button>
              {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
                    {% if messages %}
                        <ul>
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            <strong> {{ message }} </strong>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    {% endif %}
              {% endwith %}
         </form>
```

Comment: Just a guess, but I think ``onsubmit`` should be an attribute on the ``form`` tag, not on the ``input``.

Answer (score 0):

Your html code here seems to be malformed, try my example below.

```
    <form name="userDetails" class="form-userDetails" action="/userDetails" method="POST" onsubmit="return UserDetailsVal(this)">
         User ID:<input type="text" name="userId" value="{{request.form['userId']}}" class="form-control" />
    </form>
```

This should invoke JavaScript as you would intend.

Just a further note, it looks like your JavaScript will need a few tweaks to get that working as well.